# How to retrieve stripe card details through ios client

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, payment, stripe-payments

After successfully creating a card on stripe and retrieving the token, I need to get the last 4 digits of the card to allow the user to select a credit card

I would ideally like to do this through the front end where i send the token to the stripe server and get a corresponding card object but am unable to find any api in the documentation that allows me to do so.

Is there any way i can achieve this through the front end or will I have to preform this operation on my application backend ?

Comment: @aarish Molasi did u find any solution ?

Comment: @SandeepAggarwal unfortunately no, I had to retrieve the details on the backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `STPToken` class has a [`card`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/72870aac04b0d5cc01391dc166d01a7160a0ce67/Stripe/STPToken.m#L17) property, and in turn the `STPCard` class has a [`last4`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/72870aac04b0d5cc01391dc166d01a7160a0ce67/Stripe/STPCard.m#L41-L43) method. You should be able to use those to retrieve the last 4 digits of the card directly within your app.

Comment: Can you retrieve this token after the initial time it is created through the STPAPIClient? Doesn't seem to be a way to get it back.